# LINQ: convert .Single() to query notation

Tags: c#, linq

So I know the query notation

```
var word = from s in stringList
           where s.Length == 3
           select s;
```

is equivalent to the dot notation

```
var word = stringList
           .Where(s => s.Length == 3)
           .Select(s => s);
```

But how do you convert this dot notation to a query notation?

```
var word = wordsList
           .Single(p => p.Id == savedId);
```

I couldn't find much resources on Google.

Comment: Just stick with the dot notation in this case. It is the cleanest, most concise way to convey (to the programmer) what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. A lot of LINQ functions can't be used in the query syntax. At best, you can combine both and do something like

```
var word = (from p in wordsList
            where p.Id == savedId
            select p).Single()
```

but in the simple case of [`collection.Single(condition)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx), the "dot notation" seems more readable to me.

There is a list of keywords used by LINQ on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx), you can see which functions are integrated into the language from that list.

Comment: But it will not be translated exactly into `Single(condition)`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Well you can add a condition in the `Single` when its needed.

Comment: @Vache ...which would be exactly what the OP is asking to convert from.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart The condition is in the where. Or did I not understand what you're saying?

Comment: @Vache You said "you can add a condition in the `Single`"... which would result in the exact thing the OP is asking to convert to query notation.

Answer (score 3):

`Single` doesn't have an exact equivalent in query notation.

The best you can do is to wrap your query in parentheses and call .Single yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do is:

```
var word = (from w in wordsList
            where w.Id == savedId
            select w).Single();
```

but **It will not be exactly the same**. It will be transformed into

```
var word = wordsList
           .Where(p => p.Id == savedId)
           .Single();
```

Comment: As I see it, `.Where(predicate).Single()` and `.Single(predicate)` are functionally identical, and will exhibit the same runtime performance.

Comment: They are functionally identical, but they are not exactly the same. But I'm not sure about the performance. They should be **really, really small difference you should not ever carry about**.

Comment: Well [this is very interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194750/which-is-faster-singlepredicate-or-wherepredicate-single)....

Comment: Oh, I know why that is. `Single()` throws exception when it sees second item, `Single(predicate)` iterated entire collection even when it sees second matching element earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Single is not part of the query notation. You could change your first example to the following to achieve what you want:

```
var word = (from s in stringList where s.Length == 3 select s).Single();
```